# when I try to move to previous command, it covers current dir root in iterm

Tags: bash, iterm2, ps1

Hi i'm new to command line interface on OSX. before I started to code, I changed bash color I like.

```
#github branch show
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

#export PS1="\W \$"
export PS1="\[\e[0;36m\W\e[m\e[32m\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "

#hightlight path
alias ls="ls -G"
```

it works fine mostly but when i move to previous command with up and down key, previous command covers current dir like this.

```
Desktop $
Descd ~
```

is there any documentation that i can learn more about PS1 setting and solve this problem?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to enclose characters that don't advance the cursor inside `\[...\]`.

Compare your prompt on top with the correct prompt on the bottom.

```
export PS1="\[\e[0;36m\W\e[m\e[32m\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
export PS1="\[\e[0;36m\]\W\[\e[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

(I took the liberty of removing an apparently unnecessary `\e[m` from the middle of your prompt as well.)

Comment: thanks a lot @chepner it seems like i missed it when i code it XD.
Additionally can you recommend any document for learning bash command ? i want to learn more about it.